# XPath - all elements except those in header

Tags: html, xpath, web-scraping

Trying to figure out `XPATH` which match all elements except `header` or inside `header`. Let's assume that header can be detected by three conditions:

1. outer tag is `header` eg. `<header><div.....></header>`
2. outer tag has `id` which contains string "header"
3. outer tag has `class` which contains string "header"

My xpath: `//*[not(ancestor::header)] and //*[not(ancestor::*[contains(@id,"header")])] and //*[not(ancestor::*[contains(@class,"header")])]`

is not correct.

**EDIT:**
This should match all links which are inside `header`:

```
//*[ancestor::*[contains(@id,"header") or contains(@class,"header") or header]]
```

Now I want to get all elements except these.

Do you know how to make it work?

Comment: You should post sample XML to your question and state which element should and should not be selected to illustrate your request.

Comment: Do you mean `id` and `class` *contains* or *is* "header"?  Do you mean those to be attributes or elements?

Comment: @kjhughes Yes, contains or is. I just want to get all elements except those inside header or header itself.

Comment: When you ask XPath questions, always specify which version of XPath. Many problems are much easier in XPath 2.0 or 3.0, but many people are still using 1.0, so it's easy to waste a lot of time if we make wrong guesses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each of the expressions in your original XPath were being evaluated separately, testing whether there is an element in the XML document that satisfies those conditions, and returning a `boolean()`.

Now that you have combined the predicates to order select the particular element(s) that you don't want, you just need to negate the test:

```
//*[not(ancestor-or-self::header) and 
    not(ancestor::*[contains(@id,"header") or contains(@class,"header")])
   ]
```

Comment: I'm guessing this may need a tweek or two as OP's question is ambiguous in a number of dimensions, but +1 as it captures the essence of any answer given what was asked, and I'm confident you can adapt per clarifications.  For example, I suspect OP also doesn't want `header` elements themselves included, so you may need a `and not(self::header)` or `ancestor-or-self` worked in there.

Comment: @kjhughes good point, I’ve updated to exclude header from being selected